# Where to get travel advisories for Taiwan?

Tags: indian-citizens, safety, taiwan

I am an Indian citizen who may travel to Taiwan in a couple of months. I have been trying to figure out travel advisories for Taiwan. Now from what little info I have been able to gather, it seems Taiwan has very few diplomatic allies and hence finding travel advisories about Taiwan seems to be a bit difficult. I am looking to do some risk assessment for myself, something like [Why do travel advisories vary so much between countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105317/why-do-travel-advisories-vary-so-much-between-countries) so its easier to figure out how safe or unsafe the country is.

One of the issues is of course it has hurricanes and earthquake-prone country as it's near/on the faults but that's nature. Am thinking more about people and places etc.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why would the number of diplomatic allies a country has make any difference to the availability of travel advisories for that country?

Comment: it makes a difference in the sense of getting advise from different countries. Risk assessment is better if you have more than one source.

Comment: Taiwan is fine. Look out for earthquakes. Then proceed as if you're in any other "safe" country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though many countries don’t have official diplomatic relations with Taiwan (to avoid issues with the PRC), many do publish advisories nonetheless.

A few examples:

- UK: https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/taiwan
- US: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Taiwan.html

Others like India’s MEA apparently only publish advisories when they feel there’s a specific issue.

Others still may include Taiwan in advisories for China if they really want to please the PRC.

Generally, Taiwan is considered a safe place. As always, exercice proper caution as you would in any other “safe” country.

Answer (score 0):

Taiwan is a safe country, and even in the night, the security is also good in nearly every city. You can visit Taiwan without any doubts.